# Convergence for a improper integral $\int^b_a fg$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, continuity, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be continuous on [a,b) such that $\int^b_a f$ converges. If $g'$ is locally integrable and has a constant sign on [a,b), prove that $\int^b_a fg$ converges.

Edit: We can assume that the limit of g(x) as x approaches b from the left is equal to 0.

I have been trying to use the Dirichlet's Test for Integrals here, but I am unable too meet the requirements for application. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: I don't think that this is true if $g'$ is only **locally** integrable on $[a,b)$. Basically, we can take any function $g \in C^1([a,b))$ which is increasing. It is not hard to build a counterexample using this.